# Bloqueio da Interface no NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, interface, tcp, jpanel

Estou a desenvolver um programa para a comunicação entre cliente e servidor. 
Estou a desenvolver a interface gráfica do programa com base em `JPanel`/`Forms`.

Os dados do cliente são enviados corretamente para o servidor. O meu problema é quando faço para ir buscar os dados do servidor de novo para o cliente, a interface gráfica bloqueia, e não são mostrados elementos que deveriam aparecer.

**Cliente**

```
package Interfaces;

import Classes.Mensagem;
import Classes.Utilizador;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Zé Luís
 */
public class ConversaGrupo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static Utilizador userClass;
    private String serverID;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private int port = 2048;
    private String host;
    private Utilizador utilizador;
    private Mensagem mensagemServidor;
    private static PrintWriter out = null;
    private static BufferedReader in = null;

    private static String mensagemServidorThr;

    /**
     * Creates new form ConversaGrupo
     */
    public ConversaGrupo(Utilizador cd, String serverID) {
        this.userClass = cd;
        this.serverID = serverID;
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        text_toClienteEscrever = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        enviar_Button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        areaChat = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(230, 230, 230));

        jButton1.setText("CRIAR GRUPO");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList1);

        jButton2.setText("MENSAGEM PRIVADA");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout
                    .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                                      javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 301, 
                              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        enviar_Button.setText("ENVIAR");
        enviar_Button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                enviar_ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("SAIR");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        areaChat.setColumns(20);
        areaChat.setRows(5);
        areaChat.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                areaChatMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(areaChat);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(text_toClienteEscrever, 
                            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 414, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(enviar_Button, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                                          javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                              javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 333, 
                              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(text_toClienteEscrever, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
                                  40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(enviar_Button)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)))
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
                          javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                          javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void areaChatMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

        areaChat.setText("BEM-VINDO \t" + userClass.getNome());
        connectServer();

        try {
            receberDadosServidor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }

    private void enviar_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //verifica se a caixa de texto está vazia
        if (text_toClienteEscrever.getText() != null) { 
            //envia para o servidor a mensagem que o user escreveu
            out.println(userClass.getNome() + ":" + text_toClienteEscrever.getText()); 
            out.flush();
            text_toClienteEscrever.setText("");
        }

    }

    private void connectServer() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            areaChat.setText(areaChat.getText() + "\nLigação com o servidor estabelecida!\n");

            text_toClienteEscrever.requestFocus();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            areaChat.setText(areaChat.getText() + "\n Erro com o servidor\n");

        }

    }

    private void receberDadosServidor() throws IOException {
        String fromServer = null;
        while ((fromServer = in.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println("Servidor: " + fromServer);
            areaChat.setText(areaChat.getText() + "\n" + fromServer);


        }

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTextArea areaChat;
    private javax.swing.JButton enviar_Button;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField text_toClienteEscrever;
    // End of variables declaration 
}
```

A janela com os elementos abrem, mas os problemas começam quando o programa entra directamente no método `formWindowsOpened()`.

Quando entra no método e com o debugger passa pelas linhas, mas bloqueia e não aparece a mensagem "BEM VINDO" como podem verificar pela linha `areaChat.setText("BEM-VINDO \t" + userClass.getNome());`.

A interface bloqueia, e só parando a execução do servidor e cliente é que consigo que as janelas fechem.

Sei que está relacionado com o método  `receberDadosServidor()` mas não entendo o porque, da Interface, bloquear.

```
private void receberDadosServidor() throws IOException {
    String fromServer = null;
    while ((fromServer = in.readLine())!= null) {
        System.out.println("Servidor: " + fromServer);
        areaChat.setText(areaChat.getText() + "\n" + fromServer);
    } 


private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

    areaChat.setText("BEM-VINDO \t" + userClass.getNome());
    connectServer();

    try {
        receberDadosServidor();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

**Lado do Servidor**

```
import Classes.Utilizador;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Classe responsável por albergar o servidor do programa.
 *
 * @author Zé Luís
 */
public class server {

    /**
     * O servidor corre quando antige o método main.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket srvSckt = null;
        int porto = 2048;
        boolean listening = true;

        //conecao ao servidor
        try {
            srvSckt = new ServerSocket(porto);
            System.out.println("Conecção ao Servidor efectuada com sucesso!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Impossível coneção a porta \t" + porto);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        clientSocket = srvSckt.accept(); //espera por pedidos de clientes.

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String fromServerIntoServer = null;

        //  out.println(in.readLine());
        while (listening) {

            out.println(in.readLine());

        }
        srvSckt.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();  

    }

}
```

Em baixo deixo o exemplo da Interface Gráfica, onde na `TextArea` não aparece nada. Fica tudo bloqueado e só consigo fechar a janela se parar a execução do programa.
[image: Interface onde na TextArea não aparece nenhum elemento nem texto]

**Solução** 
Adicionei uma Thread a classe do cliente para nao haver concorrencia entre a interface e o socket.

```
 Thread recever = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                receberDadosServidor();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
    recever.start();
```

Classe completa

```
 private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

        areaChat.setText("BEM-VINDO \t" + userClass.getNome());
        connectServer();

        //devido a concorrencia de recursos, necessitamos de uma thread.
              Thread recever = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        receberDadosServidor();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ConversaGrupo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            recever.start();


    }
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel executa o código e simular o problema.

Comment: Essa imagem não ajuda a tornar o código executável. Se você fornecer um **[mcve]** do seu código, facilita bastante poder te ajudar.

Comment: ok, já vou melhorar.

Comment: ja arranjei solucao, adiconei uma thread por causa da concorrencia entre a coneccao e a interface.

Comment: Que bom, então responda com a solução encontrada :)